# Determining the total number of nonzero expansion terms in a (0,1)-matrix

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, graph-theory

Let $A=(a_{ij})_{n\times n}$ be a $(0,1)$-matrix such that it contains equal number of $1$s in each row and column. Is there any general method to count the total number of the nonzero terms $\prod_{i=1}^n a_{i,\sigma(i)}$ with $\sigma\in S_n$ being any permutation of the set $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$? (You can think of each $\prod_{i=1}^n a_{i,\sigma(i)}$ as an Laplacian expansion term of $\rm{det}(A)$.)

To be more specific, the matrix $A$ I study is an $\left(\frac{n!}{2}\right)\times\left(\frac{n!}{2}\right)$ matrix with the properties that

- Each row has precisely $n-1$ entries being $1$.
- For each fixed $i$, there are precisely ${n-2\choose 2}$ different $j\neq i$ such that $|\{k:a_{i,k}=a_{j,k}=1\}|=2$; and precisely $2n-4$ different $j\neq i$ such that $|\{k:a_{i,k}=a_{j,k}=1\}|=1$; and for the remaining rows we have $|\{k:a_{i,k}=a_{j,k}=1\}|=0$.
- Both the properties above also hold for columns.

Comment: You are asking for the computation of the permanent of the matrix. In general, this is hard (but maybe your special matrix has properties that make it tractable).

Comment: I agree this is in general almost intractable. I guess what I wanted to ask was if there is any known method that is likely helpful. In fact, this comes from a bipartite graph that admits a regular action on the bipartition.

Comment: You might want to trace through the literature mentioned on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computing_the_permanent#Special_cases) about the relevant of bipartite graphs being $K_{3,3}$-minor-free.